# Key out of range when adding element to a head of sorted set in java

Tags: java, sortedset, headset

I'm trying to retreive head of the sorted set, assign it to the same variable and later on add some values to it but I receive `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: key out of range`.

My code below

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class StackOverflow{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SortedSet<Integer> some_set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        some_set.add(5);
        some_set.add(3);
        some_set.add(12);
        some_set.add(15);

        some_set = some_set.headSet(10);
        some_set.add(10);

        System.out.println(some_set);
    }
}
```

I read there is something like restricted range which is set by using headSet but I coudn't find the way to prevent this. Is there a way to have unlimited upper bound when using headSet or maybe set it after the assignment? The only solution I came up with is

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class StackOverflow{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SortedSet<Integer> some_set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        some_set.add(5);
        some_set.add(3);
        some_set.add(12);
        some_set.add(15);

        SortedSet<Integer> temp_some_set = new TreeSet<Integer>(some_set.headSet(10));
        some_set = temp_some_set;
        some_set.add(10);

        System.out.println(temp_some_set);
    }
}
```

But this creates unwanted new sorted set with the elements from the head of previous set which slows the progam down when I have to do such operation houge amount of times.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `Set` returned by `headSet()`? Or why do you use `headSet()`? Do you want to work with only one `Set` or with two separated `Set`s? Why don't you just add the number 10 directly?

Comment: This is only an example, Generally I have a set and in one point of time a need to remove all elements greater than x for it then later on I need to add some new values to this set which some of them are greater than x. So I just need one set which is adjusted to my current need.

Comment: So you are looking for something like `tailSet(10).clear()`?

Comment: @Progman that's work like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your usage of `headSet` is not correct.

It should be used to obtain the subset of values from the main set. Docs - [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#headSet(E))

I believe you are to use the `last()` method for your usecase.